# how to MBProgress dialogbox click close

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.5

My code:

open dialogbox

[image]

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    //Start
    MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
    hud.labelText = @"loading...";
}
```

I am using `MBProgress` `HUD`  but I want to dialogbox click close
How to close dialog box to click close ?

Comment: The idea is to have the code that is doing the loading close the `MBProgressHud` when it's done.

Comment: yes when it's done but Clicking in the box will be closed what it's box click event ? this is my hide code [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];

Answer (score 1):

it's worked !
 (Void) touchesEnded event must use

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
[MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
}
```